# コマンドで「Python Scripts」を指定すると「パスが見つかりません」というエラーになる

Tags: windows, command-line

Pythonの入門書を見ながら設定をしていますが初めっからつまずいています。たすけて。。
はじめに、ez_setup.pyをDocuments>Python Scripsにダウンロードしました。
それから、コマンドプロンプトに
`C:￥…￥Documents￥Python Scripts` ＋Enterを打つと、
「指定されたパスが見つかりません。」と表示が出るのですがこれはなんですか？
たぶんエラー的なものやつですよね？

すごく初歩的なことなのかもしれませんが、説明いただけるとうれしいです。

Comment: multipost https://teratail.com/questions/55603

Comment: Windows はよく知りませんが、問題は Teratail でも指摘されているディレクトリ名がスペースを含んでいる事と、全角の「￥」（`cd` コマンドも抜けている？）あたりではないでしょうか。これがなぜ「質問の範囲が広すぎる」とされるのか分かりません。改善待ちにするのであれば、どこを改善する必要があるのか指摘して下さい。

Answer (score 1):

#### コマンド列は空白で区切られる

基本的なコマンド列は、コマンドと、それに与える「コマンドライン引数」からなります。
コマンドライン引数は必要ない事もあり、複数指定できる事もあります。
これらは、空白で区切ります。

```
コマンド 引数1 引数2 引数3
```

例えば、`cd`コマンドは「`cd`」がコマンド名です。そして、移動先のディレクトリを引数で受け取ります。
「`Python_Scripts`」というディレクトリに移るのでしたら、以下のようになります。

```
cd Python_Scripts
```

ここで問題になるのは、引数であるディレクトリ名が空白を含んでいる場合です。
「`Python Scripts`」に移動しようとして、以下のように実行したとします。

```
cd Python Scripts
```

これは空白で区切られますから、コマンドが`cd`、一つ目の引数が`Python`、二つ目の引数が`Scripts`と解釈されます。
よって、`Python`というディレクトリへの移動を指示した事になってしまい、そのようなディレクトリが無ければ「パスが見つからない」というエラーになります。

#### クォート内は空白で分割されない

上記のような状況に対処するため、ダブルクォート（`"`）で囲んだ文字列は分割しないというルールがあります。

```
cd "Python Scripts"
```

これで、「`Python Scripts`」へ移動出来ます。

#### Windows でのディレクトリの区切り記号は「\」

質問のコマンドには、ディレクトリを全角の円記号で区切っているという問題もあります。
Windows においては、ここらへんの事情は若干混乱していますので、以下の点を抑えておいて下さい。

Unix のディレクトリ階層の区切りには「`/`（スラッシュ）」が使われますが、Windows では「`\`（バックスラッシュ）」です。
「`\`（バックスラッシュ）」の字形は「`/`（スラッシュ）」の傾きの向きを逆にした物です。
但し、一部の環境、フォントによっては別の字形で表示されます。
日本語環境の Windows では「`￥`（全角の円記号）」を半角にした字形が使われています。